# Postgres/PSQL - exporting automatically a query to CSV using a batchfile

Tags: postgresql, cron, export-to-csv, psql

when I do manually followed commands that work like a charm

```
psql "postgresql://server:myport/base?user=me&password=password" 

\COPY (SELECT *  FROM MyTable WHERE dt_dern_modif > '2021-12-21') TO 'C:\Users\Me\notifs_dump_cron.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;
```

**I try to create a batch to save daily the content of a table in postgres to a CSV file and send it later vat ftp on a server.**

I'm using windows 10 and psql 11.13

How can I do this export ?

I try to do something like that for the moment but that don't match :
**file.bat**

```
    psql "postgresql://server:myport/base?user=me&password=password" -c "\COPY (SELECT *  FROM MyTable ') TO 'C:\Users\Me\notifs_dump_cron.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;"
```

And when I launch it that make me following response :

```
psql "postgresql://server:myport/base?user=me&password=password" -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM bng_safcom_cen.cofi;) TO 'C:\Users\SG41RPichet\Documents\notifs_dump_cron.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;"
psql : attention : option supplémentaire « \COPY (SELECT * FROM bng_safcom_cen.cofi;) TO 'C:\Users\SG41RPichet\Documents\notifs_dump_cron.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER; » ignorée
psql (11.13, serveur 10.5 (Debian 10.5-1.pgdg80+1))
Attention : l'encodage console (850) diffère de l'encodage Windows (1252).
            Les caractères 8 bits peuvent ne pas fonctionner correctement.
            Voir la section « Notes aux utilisateurs de Windows » de la page
            référence de psql pour les détails.
Connexion SSL (protocole : TLSv1.2, chiffrement : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits : 256, compression : désactivé)
Saisissez « help » pour l'aide.

table=>
```

Comment: To your question add the complete batch file script and the error message(s) you get when you run it.

Comment: I juste d'ont how to do that. For the moment, my batch is my code above. But I need, in shot to do that sequence in one line

Comment: In what shell(command line) are you running the script? What is the error you get? Best bet it is an command escaping issue, but without more information there is not much else I can say.

Comment: I use a .bat file.
And this is the content :
[code]
psql "postgresql://server:myport/base?user=me&password=password" -C "\COPY (SELECT *  FROM MyTable WHERE dt_dern_modif > '2021-12-21') TO 'C:\Users\Me\notifs_dump_cron.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;"[/code]
And response :
[code]psql : attention : option supplémentaire « \COPY (SELECT * FROM bng_safcom_cen.cofi) TO 'C:\Users\SG41RPichet\Documents\notifs_dump.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER; » ignorée
psql (11.13, serveur 10.5 (Debian 10.5-1.pgdg80+1))
[/code]
And I got the prompt

Comment: OK, that seems it's impossible to do that with connecting string. You must use a pgpass.conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that seems it's impossible to do that with connecting string. You must use a pgpass.conf file and do a file.bat like :

```
psql -d base -h host -U me -w -p 5420 -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM table WHERE dt_dern_modif > '2021-12-21') TO 'dump_cron.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV HEADER;"
```

Comment: Actually what you where using was the `URI` form which does not need to be quoted. For more info see [URI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING). Something that follows this form should work:`psql postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/base -c '\COPY csv_test from csv_test.csv with csv'`. Where `postgres:postgres` is user:password.